# Dynamic Hyperlink between different Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, dynamic, hyperlink, spreadsheet

I am really stuck and looking for help from experts.
I have hyperlink formula like this,
I have 2 different spreadsheets,
One is for the [table of contents]
and another spreadsheet is for all the tabs for those contents.
I want to put a hyperlink from the table of contents to the actual tab on the 2nd spreadsheet, also
I want to jump to the bottom of the non-empty cell.

I have some hyperlinks that work if I place them on the different tab in the same spreadsheet.
Such as,
HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=1695526833&range=A"&COUNTA('A1427903'!A:A),"A1427903!A"&COUNTA('A1427903'!A:A))

But when I put this on the 1st sheet, on [the table of contents],
it takes me to the target sheet. But it does NOT select any cells.

I have tried some other formula like filter, max,, etc  instead of counta,
But the result were same.
Some hyperlink dinamically work if its on the same spreadsheet, but when I put it on the different spreadsheet, it takes me to the sheet but does not select any cell.

Hyperlinking between different spreadsheets does not allow us to make it dynamic?
I have spent a few days trying to sort this out. I would be very grateful for any help you have on this matter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=hyperlink("SPREADSHEET_URL&range=A"&
            index(match(,0/(importrange("SPREADSHEET_ID","A1427903!A:A")<>""))),"JUMP")
```

[image]

Comment: Also prior to using the above formula directly,  first use the importrange part of formula separately to establish a link b/w both the sheets by `Allowing Access` & making sure that data is being pulled from the target sheet

Comment: Wow,, its a miracle!! It worked perfect! Than you so much for your precise and prompt reply!! You are truly a genius!